# If/Else Statement Failing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to write a simple script that will look at a credit number rating and show the corresponding text rating. The if-else statement breaks when I get to the second else/if statement and I cannot figure out why so anything over 601 just reads "POOR".

```
credit = 690;

if (credit <= 600) {
    document.write("VERY POOR");
} 
else if (credit >= 601 || credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
else if (credit >= 658 || credit <= 719){
    document.write("FAIR");
}
else if (credit >= 720 || credit <= 780){
    document.write("GOOD");
}
else {
    (credit >= 781 || credit <= 850);
    document.write("EXCELLENT");
}
```

Comment: `||` means "or", not "and"

Comment: `(credit >= 781 || credit <= 850);` <-- This doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your code fails if someone has a credit score of `600.5` btw (and never assume number values are always integer in JavaScript). Hence the idiomatic way to do range-comparisons in JS (and in general) is to use a sequence of ever-decreasing comparisons using _only_ `>=` (or ever-increasing comparisons using only `<=`).

Comment: You do not need the >= portion.... that is going to work out because the one before it will remove the things less `if (credit <= 600) {
    document.write("VERY POOR");
} 
else if (credit <= 657){ ....`

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the `||` with `&&`.

|| means OR, meanwhile && means AND. You need to check if credit is greater than 601 AND lower than 657.

Try this way:

```
credit = 690;

if (credit <= 600) {
    document.write("VERY POOR");
} 
else if (credit >= 601 && credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
else if (credit >= 658 && credit <= 719){
    document.write("FAIR");
}
else if (credit >= 720 && credit <= 780){
    document.write("GOOD");
}
else {
    (credit >= 781 && credit <= 850);
    document.write("EXCELLENT");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is that when you code:

```
else if (credit >= 601 || credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
```

This is true, so it will say POOR, because you are dealing with or clause witch means (True or False) = (False or True) = True:

The solution is removing the first argument:

```
let credit = 690;

if(credit <= 600) {
    console.log(credit)
    document.write("VERY POOR");
} 
else if (credit >= 601 && credit <= 657){
    console.log(credit)
    document.write("POOR");
}
else if (credit >= 658 && credit <= 719){
    console.log(credit)
    document.write("FAIR");
}
else if (credit >= 720 && credit <= 780){
    console.log(credit)
    document.write("GOOD");
}
else {
    (credit >= 781 && credit <= 850);
    console.log(credit)
    document.write("EXCELLENT");
}
```

ps: Code need the 'and' clause (&&) between the two values to work. Because, (True and False) = (False and True) = (False and False) = False. Its only true when when both members are true!

Answer (score 1):

in these cases you must use the &&

&& Operator will define that the two values ​​need to be true,
OR Operator will define that to execute, only one value is true.

you can read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

```
    let credit = 750;

if (credit <= 600) {
    document.write("VERY POOR");
} 
else if (credit >= 601 && credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
else if (credit >= 658 && credit <= 719){
    document.write("FAIR");
}
else if (credit >= 720 && credit <= 780){
    document.write("GOOD");
}
else {
    (credit >= 781 && credit <= 850);
    document.write("EXCELLENT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have confused AND and OR boolean condition, your condition :

```
else if (credit >= 601 || credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
```

catches everything that superior to 601, because that is literally what you asked it to do. If you want a range check, your should write :

```
else if (credit >= 601 && credit <= 657){
    document.write("POOR");
}
```

and so on for each of you else if statement. :)